# How to Initializing DataTable On the Div load Page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I want to wear a DataTable but I want to assume the DataTable in div load page

this is my code

**index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />   

        <h2>Data Pendidikan</h2>
        <a href="#dialog-k" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" id='0'> Tambah Data </a>
        <br />

        <div id="data-tab">
        </div>


<script src="../../assets/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>

(function($) {
    // fungsi dijalankan setelah seluruh dokumen ditampilkan
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        // deklarasikan variabel
        var kd_k = 0;
        var main = "../../app/pendidikan/pendidikan.data.php";
        $('#table-1').DataTable();
        // tampilkan data k dari berkas k.data.php 
        // ke dalam <div id="data-k"></div>
        $("#data-tab").load(main);

    });
}) (jQuery);


    </script>
```

**pendidikan.data.php**

```
<table class="table table-bordered datatable" id="table-1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-hide="phone">Rendering engine</th>
                    <th>Browser</th>
                    <th data-hide="phone">Platform(s)</th>
                    <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Engine version</th>
                    <th>CSS grade</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                    <td>Trident</td>
                    <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                    <td>Win 95+</td>
                    <td class="center">4</td>
                    <td class="center">X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even gradeC">
                    <td>Trident</td>
                    <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
                    <td>Win 95+</td>
                    <td class="center">5</td>
                    <td class="center">C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd gradeA">
                    <td>Trident</td>
                    <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
                    <td>Win 95+</td>
                    <td class="center">5.5</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even gradeA">
                    <td>Trident</td>
                    <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
                    <td>Win 98+</td>
                    <td class="center">6</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="odd gradeA">
                    <td>Trident</td>
                    <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
                    <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
                    <td class="center">7</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even gradeA">
                    <td>Trident</td>
                    <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
                    <td>Win XP</td>
                    <td class="center">6</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.7</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
                    <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.9</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Camino 1.0</td>
                    <td>OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Camino 1.5</td>
                    <td>OSX.3+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
                    <td class="center">1.7</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
                    <td>Win 98SE+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.7</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.1</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.2</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.3</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.4</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.5</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.6</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.7</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
                    <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Gecko</td>
                    <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
                    <td>Gnome</td>
                    <td class="center">1.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Webkit</td>
                    <td>Safari 1.2</td>
                    <td>OSX.3</td>
                    <td class="center">125.5</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Webkit</td>
                    <td>Safari 1.3</td>
                    <td>OSX.3</td>
                    <td class="center">312.8</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Webkit</td>
                    <td>Safari 2.0</td>
                    <td>OSX.4+</td>
                    <td class="center">419.3</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Webkit</td>
                    <td>Safari 3.0</td>
                    <td>OSX.4+</td>
                    <td class="center">522.1</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Webkit</td>
                    <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
                    <td>OSX.4+</td>
                    <td class="center">420</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Webkit</td>
                    <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
                    <td>iPod</td>
                    <td class="center">420.1</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Webkit</td>
                    <td>S60</td>
                    <td>S60</td>
                    <td class="center">413</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 7.0</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 7.5</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 8.0</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 8.5</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 9.0</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 9.2</td>
                    <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 9.5</td>
                    <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera for Wii</td>
                    <td>Wii</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Nokia N800</td>
                    <td>N800</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
                    <td>Nintendo DS</td>
                    <td class="center">8.5</td>
                    <td class="center">C/A<sup>1</sup>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeC">
                    <td>KHTML</td>
                    <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
                    <td>KDE 3.1</td>
                    <td class="center">3.1</td>
                    <td class="center">C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>KHTML</td>
                    <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
                    <td>KDE 3.3</td>
                    <td class="center">3.3</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>KHTML</td>
                    <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
                    <td>KDE 3.5</td>
                    <td class="center">3.5</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeX">
                    <td>Tasman</td>
                    <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
                    <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeC">
                    <td>Tasman</td>
                    <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
                    <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
                    <td class="center">1</td>
                    <td class="center">C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeC">
                    <td>Tasman</td>
                    <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
                    <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
                    <td class="center">1</td>
                    <td class="center">C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Misc</td>
                    <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
                    <td>Embedded devices</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeA">
                    <td>Misc</td>
                    <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
                    <td>Embedded devices</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeX">
                    <td>Misc</td>
                    <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
                    <td>Embedded devices</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeX">
                    <td>Misc</td>
                    <td>Links</td>
                    <td>Text only</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeX">
                    <td>Misc</td>
                    <td>Lynx</td>
                    <td>Text only</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeC">
                    <td>Misc</td>
                    <td>IE Mobile</td>
                    <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeC">
                    <td>Misc</td>
                    <td>PSP browser</td>
                    <td>PSP</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="gradeU">
                    <td>Other browsers</td>
                    <td>All others</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td class="center">-</td>
                    <td class="center">U</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Rendering engine</th>
                    <th>Browser</th>
                    <th>Platform(s)</th>
                    <th>Engine version</th>
                    <th>CSS grade</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

but on the my script the datatable library is not called
Please The Solution to fix my script :D Thanks

Comment: you should load main first and then call datatable method

Answer (score 0):

Initialize table once page has been loaded as shown below:

```
$("#data-tab").load(main, function(){
    $('#table-1').DataTable();
});
```